# DAO returns the NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception

I have created a `ExamineeDao` to get the `Examinee` by using their Id,hall Ticket no etc..

In the Service I Autowired the `ExamineeDao` a follows

```
@Autowired
private ExamineeDao examineeDao;
```

I try to access the `ExamineeDao` within a function of a service as

```
Examinee examinee = examineeDao.findById(id);\\line no 85 in the generateQMH
```

When i execute the code the Server shows the `Error` as

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at cdac.examination.ccat.service.exam.ExamQuestionsListServiceImpl.generateQMH(ExamQuestionsListServiceImpl.java:85)
    at cdac.examination.ccat.service.exam.ExamQuestionsListServiceImpl.getQAIPath(ExamQuestionsListServiceImpl.java:48)
```

The above Exception is due to the `examineeDao` returns the `NULL` value.

Any one advice me what are the possibilities to get this kind of error and what I need to change?

Comment: How do you get an instance of the service?

Comment: Turn on `Spring`'s logging and take a look at what the `@Autowired` is doing.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably in error in your spring configuration. The only chance of a `NullPointerException` being thrown at that line is if `examineeDao` is `null`, so it is probably not injected properly. Run a debugger and it will show you pretty fast.

It might be that the ExamineeDao is not made available for autowiring, post your spring configuration (and annotated examineeDao-class) please.

Comment: This should be a comment. Not an answer.